# convert title to slug without slug option in API

Tags: reactjs, api

API doesn't have slug only Id how to convert they title to slug without any slug option in API
for example
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
above API doesn't have slug I want to use title as slug but pull data with id so, is it possible?

```
<Link
  to={`/API/${convertToSlug(props.name)}`}
  state={{ id: `${props.id}` }}
  className="w-full md:w-1/4 h-56 relative"
>
  <img
    src={props.image}
    alt=""
    className="h-full w-full bg-cover object-cover"
  />
  {props.status && (
    <div className="absolute bg-green top-4 ltr:left-0 rtl:right-0 px-4 ltr:rounded-r-md rtl:rounded-l-md py-2 z-10 font-bold opacity-90 text-white capitalize">
      <h3> {newStatus}</h3>
    </div>
  )}
</Link>
```

in the above code i tried to pass id to the next component but the issue when try access the page directly it doesn't work as it don't have values in the id.